# Can I put different parts of a Javalite project in separate Maven repos?

Tags: java, maven, activejdbc, javalite

In my Javalite project, I have my models, controllers, config files and other classes. I want to reuse some of the parts in this project since in my other Javalite projects, I want to use the same models but I don't want to simply copy-paste or rewrite my model classes. Is it possible to put my model classes in a Maven repo, and simply import that repo whenever I want to use the models in any of my Javalite projects? I also want to reuse some of my controllers, so I'm also asking the same thing for the controllers too.

Comment: Use the other projects/modules as dependencies ?

Comment: Err, "yes of course". But how far you want to go drastically influences just how much work this is going to be. Is this only to do things on one development machine, or are you looking to set this up for multiple development machines / locations?

Comment: @khmarbaise The reason I asked this is because for an ActiveJDBC (a module of Javalite) to work properly is to put all the model classes inside a certain package inside the source folder. I wasn't sure whether defining the module classes under a submodule would work well with the architecture.

Comment: @Gimby Please see my other comment. I know it can be done on normal Java projects, I just wasn't sure whether it would work well with Javalite's architecture. As for your question, I'm not sure I understand. Currently I'm the only one working on this project but I want things to be tidy and reusable, and I don't know if the company will assign more people to work on this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaLite projects are Maven modules, and as such, you can create a more complex Maven project with sub-modules that depend on one another. In fact, almost every JavaLite project I build is broken down like that. Here is how we structure modules:

```
root module
  |
  +-- common
  |
  +-- web-customer-ui
  |
  +-- web-internal-admin
  |
  +-- web-rest-api
  |
  +-- another_module
```

Typically, all these modules will want to access the same database, so the ActiveJDBC models are placed into `common`. The `common` will also host common services and other util classes shared by other apps (you know.. common stuff :)).

Then, there are web apps - these are ActiveWeb projects with their respective controllers, views, etc. Each of the web apps depends on common and will use the same services and models.

We do not share controllers across different web apps, even of their names and features are the same.

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Igor, I will try doing this with a dummy project and see if this is what I want to do with my project.